# Supervisord / Celery output logs

Tags: django, celery, supervisord

I am using Supervisor to manage celery. The supervisor config file for celery contains the following 2 entries:

```
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/celery.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/celery_err.log
```

What is confusing me is that although Celery is working properly and all tasks are being successfully completed, they are all written to celery_err.log. I thought that would only be for errors. The celery.log file only shows the normal celery startup info.  Is the behaviour of writing successful task completion to the error log correct?

**Note** - tasks are definitely completing successfully (emails being sent, db entries made etc).

Answer (score 4):

I met the same phenomenon just like you.This is because of celery's loging mechanism. Just see the setup_task_loggers method of [celery logger source](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/log.html#Logging.setup_task_loggers).

> If `logfile` is not specified, then `sys.stderr` is used.

So, clear enough? Celery uses sys.stderr when logfile is not specified.

**Solution:**

1. You can use supervisord redirect_stderr = true flag to combine two log files into one. I'm using this one.
2. Config the celery logfile option.

Comment: celery has `def _detect_handler(self, logfile=None)` which contains code: `logfile = sys.__stderr__ if logfile is None else logfile`

Answer (score 0):

> Is the behaviour of writing successful task completion to the error log correct?

No, its not. I am having same setup and logging is working fine.

celery.log has task info

```
[2015-07-23 11:40:07,066: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: foo[b5a6e0e8-1027-4005-b2f6-1ea032c73d34]
[2015-07-23 11:40:07,494: INFO/MainProcess] Task foo[b5a6e0e8-1027-4005-b2f6-1ea032c73d34] succeeded in 0.424549156s: 1
```

celery_err.log has some warnings/errors. Try restarting supervisor process.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you could be having is that python buffers output by default

In your supervisor file, you can disable this by setting the PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable, see below my Django example supervisor file

```
[program:celery-myapp]
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myapp.settings.production",PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
command=/home/me/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/celery -A myapp worker -B -l DEBUG
directory=/home/me/www/saleor
user=me

stdout_logfile=/home/me/www/myapp/log/supervisor-celery.log
stderr_logfile=/home/me/www/myapp/log/supervisor-celery-err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
```

Comment: Could you explain why disable PYTHONUNBUFFERED to log the right place, please?

Comment: @stan liu   When PYTHONUNBUFFERED is set to a non-empty string (e.g., “1”), it disables output buffering. This means that when your Python script writes data to stdout or stderr, the data is immediately flushed or displayed on the console as soon as it’s generated, rather than being held in a buffer and displayed all at once. This can be helpful when you want to see real-time output from your script or when you’re dealing with log files and need to ensure that log entries are written immediately.